# WordPress self made onepager theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a onepager template. My approach is very simple and it works more or less. The only problem that I have is, that I don't find a proper way to use the different templates on one single page. For illustrative purposes, see below:

[image]

Is there a way to include the different templates on one single page?

I would like to define the order of pages by setting the order on each page:
[image]

My current code:

```html
get_header(); ?>
 <?php $args = array(
  'sort_order' => 'asc',
  'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
  'hierarchical' => 1,
  'exclude' => '',
  'include' => '',
  'meta_key' => '',
  'meta_value' => '',
  'authors' => '',
  'child_of' => 0,
  'parent' => -1,
  'exclude_tree' => '',
  'number' => '',
  'offset' => 0,
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'publish'
 ); 
 $pages = get_pages($args);
 foreach($pages as $page){
  ?>
  <section style="height:400px;border-color:red;color:red;">
  <?php
  print_r($page);
  ?>
   <section id="banner" class="banner-section vertical-center">
    <div class="container text-center">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12" id="">
       <h1><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12" id="">
       <p><?php echo $page->post_content; ?></p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>
   <?php
 }
 ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The code works, but I can't set different tags for each page. E.g. the banner page always must have a blue background with white font color - the news page must have white background with blue font color including the featured image and the memories page must collect all blog posts.

Any help to create a onepager template?

Comment: A simple `include()` won't work?

Comment: Well, that could work yes. The problem then is that the user isn't able to reorder the pages on the onepager. :-(

Comment: Well then you need to provide A LOT more information about what you want... Including the code you're currently working with.

Comment: The "WordPress" way to do this is typically using the function get_template_part() --
> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/ However, I agree with other posters in that we'd probably need to know a bit more about how your page structure is going to be reordered and customized to be able to provide more specific advice.

Comment: Added some additional information. Hope that helps ;-) Thank you very much guys.